# how to extract mysql version by bash script in centos 6

Tags: mysql, bash, scripting, versioning

I need to extract the mysql version in a bash script on CentOS 6 for a minimum requirements check

Example:

```
# mysql -V
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.43, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1
# mysql -V 
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.24, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

Should I use something like `mysql -V| grep ...`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[!520]#

```
mysql --version|awk '{ print $5 }'|awk -F\, '{ print $1 }'
```

Output is :

```
5.5.41
```

Answer (score 3):

For the above two examples, if you want the "14.14" string:

```
mysql -V | awk '{print $3}'
```

If want the "5.x.x" string:

```
mysql -V | awk '{print $5}'
```

I can't guarantee that the strings will be in the same format across major versions, though. Also, this could probably also be performed with `sed` and some clever regexing.

If you want a check against installed RPMs, then you could go with:

```
rpm -qi mysql | grep Version | awk '{print $3}'
```

Comment: # rpm -qi mysql 
package mysql is not installed
but
# mysql -V|awk '{ print $5 }'|awk -F\, '{ print $1 }'
5.6.24